# how to scrape web data from multiple unknown data types/format websites?

Tags: web-scraping

Web scraping used to be "easy" before inline css, jquery, 3rd party scripts, iframes, unmatched tags, random  tags, etc, etc.

Without me basically "creating" the google search engine from scratch as a single person... (and the 100,000's of thousands of hours gone into that)... is there any good pre-made software solutions to extract generic data types? (I'm guessing I'd need to pay for something, because looking at what I need to extract I go "bleah").

I need to extract the data content (text, dates, links, etc) from several thousand sites, without knowing what format it is in. (Some is dynamically generated on the fly, some is included in iframes, some is hidden in obfuscated javascript code, etc, etc). Just one big mess, and I'm trying to figure out how to make nice order from it, without manually visiting every website by hand and doing a cut & paste.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The question is way too broad... Also asking for software recommendations (or any off-site resources) is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Take a look at this M.I.T bot [DiffBot](http://www.diffbot.com/) I think it's what you're describing

Comment: thanks. Took a look - it 'kind' of does what I need - but I was finding if the webpage was heavy on the jQuery (dynamic content) - or did not contain say 500+ words - it had difficulty identifying/extracting information... I 'might' be able to use this to some degree - do you have any other recommendations? thanks!

Comment: & @audrius - no, it is not a "way too broad" question. READ what I asked, and try to understand the question.

I need a generic/all purpose data extractor. I'm trying to scrape unknown data websites and finding its a pain in the arse because "everyone" designs their site differently. and as far as I know - it is perfectly fine asking for recommendations as I've seen many other questions answered with specific software solutions, etc.

Comment: adding a comment again to rafael - I'm testing this with random urls... and it "kind" of works. 50% of the time it gives me the information I want - and 50% of the time is way off base. (I.e., instead of say product info, it will give me a little writeup of an advertisement the site has to buy stuff)... any other recommendations? thanks!

Comment: Please read [help/on-topic] on what is off-topic here, specifically: "Questions asking us to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."